# Multi-steps direct forecasting in AR(2) model through bayesian estimation of the model

Tags: time-series, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

I'm estimating an AR(2) model using Bayesian methods through Gibbs sampling and I want to perform 4 step ahead multi-steps direct forecasts. Inside the MCMC loop in each iteration I'm drawing the variance and the vector of coefficients (the intercept and the coefficients for the first and the second lag). Hence I can easily perform iterated forecasting, but what about multi-steps direct forecasting? Does somebody have a reference on this?

Answer (score 1):

Forecasting an AR(2) model simply uses an iterative approach.

Your first point forecast $\hat{y}_{T+1}$ relies on your last two historical observations $y_T$ and $y_{T-1}$ (since your AR order is 2). So plug these two in to get your point forecast $\hat{y}_{T+1}$.

Now, your next forecast $\hat{y}_{T+2}$ relies on $y_T$ (which you have, it's your last historical observation) and $y_{T+1}$ (which you don't have, it's your first forecast period). So instead of $y_{T+1}$, we simply use the forecast $\hat{y}_{T+1}$ which we just calculated above.

And so forth for $\hat{y}_{T+t}$. Since you have a posterior distribution for your coefficients, just perform this within each MCMC run and take the average at the end. For quantile forecasts, draw additional noise terms $\epsilon_{T+t}$, add these to your forecasts and finally take quantiles.

More information can be found in [this free online open forecasting textbook](https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-forecasting.html).

Comment: Yes but this is iterated forecasting; I'm asking about direct multi-steps forecasting.

Comment: Iteration **is** how you do multi-step forecasting in AR models. Alternatively, of course, you can express $\hat{y}_{T+1}$ as a function of $y_T$ and $y_{T-1}$ and substitute this expression into the formula for $\hat{y}_{T+2}$. Which amounts to precisely the same thing.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.princeton.edu/~mwatson/papers/hstep_3.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjKzdO82_voAhWFi8MKHcs6CowQFjALegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw3y1O0OB3yFwG4_4vGGiHL3

Comment: That is something different. The authors use horizon-specific models, fitting one model for one-step ahead forecasts, another one for two-step ahead forecasts and so forth. If you have a dedicated model for two-step ahead forecasts, then you simply evaluate this model to obtain a two-step ahead forecast. Of course you can do the same thing: simply fit a model directly to your four steps horizon, and then evaluate it. (I would then expect the optimum model not to be AR(2) any more - that would translate into an AR(5) model with only $\phi_5\neq 0$ and $\phi_4\neq 0$, unrealistic.)

Comment: Yes, this is called multi-step DIRECT forecasting (which is what I'm asking from the beginning). My problem is that inside the MCMC loop I draw the coefficients for the first and second lag which are not the coefficients I need to perform the direct multistep forecast.

Comment: You can train your model and run your MCMC for a direct multi-step target value. I'm afraid I don't quite understand what your question is.

Comment: Ok, so basically you say that since for 1 to 4 step ahead forecasts I have 4 vectors of coefficients I have to run 4 different models, hence 4 different MCMC loops, right?

Comment: Exactly! (And you might want different model forms for the different forecasts, maybe AR(2) for one- and two-step forecasts and AR(1) for three- and four-step forecasts. Use your order selection procedure separately for each horizon.)